# Mean for rows with common pattern

Tags: r, pattern-matching, mean

I would like calculate mean values for rows that have common pattern in column names, mean_A for row with column names containing "_1", "_2" and mean_B for rows with column names containing "_3" and "_4".

Here is my example:

```
structure(list(sample1_type_1 = c(10.591, 41.37), sample1_type_2 = c(9.985, 
35.691), sample1_type_3 = c(9.153, 35.317), sample1_type_4 = c(7.175, 
13.781), sample2_type_1 = c(10.704, 15.821), sample2_type_2 = c(11.049, 
23.959), sample2_type_3 = c(8.261, 18.191), sample2_type_4 = c(17.316, 
21.5), sample3_type_1 = c(21.218, 22.039), sample3_type_2 = c(16.087, 
21.235), sample3_type_3 = c(12.33, 20.211), sample3_type_4 = c(11.748, 
17.264)), .Names = c("sample1_type_1", "sample1_type_2", "sample1_type_3", 
"sample1_type_4", "sample2_type_1", "sample2_type_2", "sample2_type_3", 
"sample2_type_4", "sample3_type_1", "sample3_type_2", "sample3_type_3", 
"sample3_type_4"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I would appreciate a more elegant way then the following:

```
df$sample1_A <- rowMeans(subset(df, select = c(sample1_type_1, sample1_type_2)), na.rm = TRUE)
df$sample2_A <- rowMeans(subset(df, select = c(sample2_type_1, sample2_type_2)), na.rm = TRUE)
df$sample3_A <- rowMeans(subset(df, select = c(sample3_type_1, sample3_type_2)), na.rm = TRUE)
df$sample1_B <- rowMeans(subset(df, select = c(sample1_type_3, sample1_type_4)), na.rm = TRUE)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a loop for this.  Create `vector` of column names, use `Map` to get the `rowMeans` of the corresponding column names and assign the `list` elements to the new `vector` of column names ('i2')

```
i1 <- paste0("sample", 1:3, "_type_")
i2 <- paste0(sub("type_", "", i1), rep(LETTERS[1:2], c(3, 1)))
df[i2] <- Map(function(x, y) rowMeans(df[c(x,y)]),
    paste0(i1, rep(c(1, 3), c(3, 1))), paste0(i1, rep(c(2, 4), c(3, 1))))
```